# does ice accumulation of wing affect its flutter speed

Tags: icing, flutter, aeroelasticity

I am trying to find a possible link between wing icing and flutter.
I want to know if ice accretion mass will change aeroelastic properties of the wing.
Does wing icing affect the flutter speed of wing? Will ice accretion cause early onset of flutter?

Comment: The amount of ice needed to affect "aeroelastic properties" would already be drastically affecting lifting properties.

Comment: I agree with Robert. By the time enough ice were to accumulate to affect the wing's structural properties, you won't be flying anymore.